# Transform dict of lists to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I want to transform this `dict` to CSV:

```
{
  "California": ["San Fransisco", "Los Angeles","Oakland"],
  "Texas": ["Dallas", "Houston", "Austin"],
  "Florida": ["Miami", "Tampa"],
  ...
}
```

I want the following output:

```
California,San Fransisco
California,Los Angeles
California,Oakland
Texas,Dallas
Texas,Houston
Texas,Austin
Florida,Miami
Florida,Tampa
```

I wrote this code. This works well, but I wonder if there is a more pythonic way to do the same.

```py
import csv

d = {
    "California": ["San Fransisco", "Los Angeles","Oakland"],
    "Texas": ["Dallas", "Houston", "Austin"],
    "Florida": ["Miami", "Tampa"]
}

with open("./out.csv", "w") as f:
  header = ["state", "city"]
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerow(header)
  for i in d.keys():
    for j in d[i]:
      writer.writerow([i,j])
```

Comment: Btw, this sort of operation is maybe called going from jagged array (I would say wide data, but the rows aren't all the same length) to tall data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/), the standard indentation for Python code is 4 spaces.  Since whitespace is significant in Python, this is a pretty strong convention that you should follow.

The code itself isn't bad, but you could make it a bit more elegant using [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`csvwriter.writerows()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows).  You can also use more meaningful variable names than `i` and `j`.

```
import itertools

with open("./out.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["state", "city"])
    for state, cities in d.items():
        writer.writerows(itertools.product([state], cities))
```

Comment: I also like that you've switched to `d.items()` instead of `d.keys()`.

Comment: That would be a more useful comment if you commented on the difference and why it's an improvement, @Teepeemm.

Comment: Using .item() is clearly better and more readable too, if you look at the original implementation (`for j in d[i]:..`). Plus, applying itertools instead of a loop is smart.

Answer (score 2):

Flatten the dictionary into rows using clear variable names:

```
header = ["state", "city"]

rows = (
    [state, city]
    for state, cities in d.items()
    for city in cities
)
```

Then write those rows to a csv:

```
with open("./out.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```